# How do I properly handle the location of resource files for a program using CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I have a C++ program that needs to open some XML files when it runs to gather configuration information about the system.  I am using CMake to manage the build and deployment (RPM) and am trying to figure out the most elegant way to deal with installing these XML files and allowing my program to find them when it runs.

Ideally, this solution will:

1)  Allow the program to run from its build location (for testing/debug mode) in which the XML files reside in the source directory

2) When the program is installed to /usr or /usr/local (or whatever) the XML files will be installed to /usr/share/somePath/ConfigFiles/ and the program will know to look for them there.

My current solution is to create a config.h.in file that defines the source path of the XML files and the install path (/usr/share/...).  When the program runs it checks one directory and then the other.  Is there a better way to handle this so that the program knows whether a "make install" has been executed and it will know exactly where to find them without having to check both locations?

Comment: Aside from looking into source dir in `Debug` mode and install dir in `Release` mode - no. What's problem for checking two locations?

Comment: @arrowdodger there is a risk that I will be running a test build and it could use the XML files from a location I didn't expect.  Not that this is impossible to deal with, but I am hoping that someone came up with a clean way to deal with this.  Once I do a 'make install', there's no need for the program to ever look in the source directory for the files.